# Adding the Intro.JS library to a Vue-Cli / Webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, intro.js

I'm building my first project using **vue-cli** and **webpack** and I'm not sure how to properly use an external JavaScript library to my project.

I want to add the **Intro.js** library which simply requires me to import the **intro.js**, add some tags to some HTML elements, and call the **introJs().start()** function.

I've installed the library with `npm install introj.js --save`

I've imported the library by adding `import introJS from 'intro.js'` into my `<script>` section of my `App.vue` file.

I've checked the compiled `app.js` file and I know introJS is being compiled so everything is good there.

My question is, where do I put `introJs().start()`?  I tried putting it in the `mounted()` function of the `App.vue` file but that doesn't work.

Additional Info:  When I try to run `introJS().start()` from the `mounted ()` method in `App.vue` I receive this error: `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_intro_js___default(...) is not a function"`

Comment: What about putting it in `main.js` before `new Vue({...})` ?

Comment: I tried that but I still get the error above stating that start is not a function.

Comment: Try this `introJS.introJs().start()`

Comment: That did it!  I knew it was going to be something simple.  How did you figure it out?  Why do I reference it like that?

Comment: Cool. after importing introJS. I stored a global reference to it `window.introJS = introJS`. Then inspected it in the console.

Comment: But if I open the console and type window.introJS it says its undefined.  It still works but I would like to know how to view the object in console as that could help me troubleshoot things like this in the future.

Comment: Never mind.  I misread.  You created the global reference.  I thought it was created automatically.

Comment: Yes, the console is your friend. if it's undefined then you might have missed importing the library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
const { introJS } = require('intro.js')
introJS().start()
```

Comment: For me it says that `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')`. Do I have to use it with older version of intro.js like 2.9.3 or what?